# MySQL, UPDATE Syntax adding multiple IDs for one value

Tags: mysql

I want this code to run multiple IDs.

```
UPDATE `tukmens_cal`.`uni1_planets` SET `nano_factory` = '19' WHERE `uni1_planets`.`id` = 10;
```

For example: `id` = 10, 11, 12;

But I've looked online and there's no syntax that works, I've tried many ways and nothing works for me.

Comment: Hi there Uldons, please, all answers are right but the one from @Moher was first, so you must accept his answer. To do so, just click on the V icon click on the left of his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `IN`:

```
UPDATE tukmens_cal.uni1_planets 
SET nano_factory = '19' 
WHERE uni1_planets.id IN (10,11,12);
```

Comment: hahaha don't even know who answered first! I will upvote yours in good will! cheers :)

Comment: i was 2 sec sooner. but thanks @JorgeCampos too. i will upvote him for you ;)

Comment: Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IN`

```
UPDATE tukmens_cal.uni1_planets 
   SET nano_factory = '19' 
 WHERE uni1_planets.id IN (10, 11, 12);
```

Comment: oh jeez, i was 2 secs sooner.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `IN` operator:

```
UPDATE `tukmens_cal`.`uni1_planets`
SET    `nano_factory` = '19'
WHERE  `uni1_planets`.`id` IN (10, 11, 12);
```